# Kotlin Native Pointer initialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have a little bit of a fight with Kotlin Native and the runtime. In short: I am building a jvmti agent, linking a dynamic library.

Now I have following case, what I like to achieve can be expressed in C like:

```
char* class_sig; 
(*jvmti)->GetClassSignature(object_klass, &class_sig, NULL) 
do something with class_sig.... 
(*jvmti)->Deallocate((unsigned char*) class_sig);
```

So in that case the jvmti environment allocates the memory for class_sig, that is why I have to deallocate through the jvmti environment.

How can this be achieved in Kotlin? I am a little on the fence regarding calling nativeheap.alloc, wouldn't that cause a memory leak because the jvmti environment already allocates memory?

Or can I just do:

```
val signaturePtr = nativeHeap.alloc<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>()
        
jvmti?.pointed?.pointed?.GetClassSignature?.invoke(jvmti, klass, signaturePtr.ptr, null)

Call jvmti dealloc?
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Native way is to use `memScoped` [blocks](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/mem-scoped.html) for such task. Take a look at [official guide for C interop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html#pass-pointers-to-bindings)

If you write

```kotlin
memScoped {
    val signaturePtr = alloc<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>()
    //...
}
```

Kotlin will take care of memory deallocation inside `memScoped` block, no need to invoke jmti Deallocate